# Assigning a value on remaining blanks in a category without impacting others

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign the remaining location value in `apple` category into `others`, but I don't want the location for `banana` and `waterloon` to get touched through the assignment. This means that I cannot just convert all the blanks to `others`. What's the safe way to do this at scale?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'fruit_tag': {0: 'apple', 1: 'apple', 2: 'banana', 3: 'apple', 4: 'watermelon'}, 'location': {0: 'Hong Kong', 1: 'Tokyo', 2: '', 3: '', 4: ''}, 'rating': {0: 'bad', 1: 'good', 2: 'good', 3: 'bad', 4: 'good'}, 'measure_score': {0: 0.9529434442520142, 1: 0.952498733997345, 2: 0.9080725312232971, 3: 0.8847543001174927, 4: 0.8679852485656738}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data);df

    fruit_tag   location rating  measure_score
0       apple  Hong Kong    bad       0.952943
1       apple      Tokyo   good       0.952499
2      banana              good       0.908073
3       apple               bad       0.884754
4  watermelon              good       0.867985
```

Expected output

```
    fruit_tag   location rating  measure_score
0       apple  Hong Kong    bad       0.952943
1       apple      Tokyo   good       0.952499
2      banana              good       0.908073
3       apple     Others    bad       0.884754
4  watermelon              good       0.867985
```

Comment: Do you want to fill all the empty location with other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame.loc` with the good condition :

- fruit is `apple`
- `location` is empty

```
df.loc[(df['fruit_tag'] == 'apple') & (df['location'] == ""), 'location'] = 'others'
```